# Python 2.7.15 MongoDb Authentication Failed

Tags: python, mongodb

I recently had a go at setting up a MongoDb server on Ubuntu 16.04. I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04)

I succesfully managed to bind the IP of the server, and allowed ufw rules to the host I'm trying to connect from to MongoDb's port, so I assume everything is working there.

The problem is I'm now trying to connect using the user I created. This is the code I'm using:

```
Con = MongoClient('mongodb://IP.OF.SERVER:27017/')
db = Con.playerDb.authenticate('USER','PASSWORD')
```

But I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\AC\Documents\AC\Servers\tests.py", line 5, in <module>
db = Con.playerDb.authenticate('USERNAME','PASSWORD')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 995, in authenticate
connect=True)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 410, in _cache_credentials
sock_info.authenticate(credentials)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 304, in authenticate
auth.authenticate(credentials, self)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 436, in authenticate
auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 416, in _authenticate_default
return _authenticate_scram_sha1(credentials, sock_info)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 188, in _authenticate_scram_sha1
res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 201, in command
check_keys, self.listeners, self.max_bson_size)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 94, in command
helpers._check_command_response(response_doc, msg, allowable_errors)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 193, in _check_command_response
raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
OperationFailure: command SON([('saslStart', 1), ('mechanism', 'SCRAM-SHA-1'), ('payload', Binary('n,,n=USERNAME,r=PASSWORD', 0)), ('autoAuthorize', 1)]) on namespace playerDb.$cmd failed: Authentication failed.
```

I've tried a few other suggestions like add the following:

```
mechanism = 'SCRAM-SHA-1'
```

I've also tried different variations of MongoClient() that others have suggested but to be honest I have no idea what actually is the problem. I only created an admin user, bound the server's IP so it listens and set some ufw rules, so not sure why the authentication failed if I'm passing the correct user+pass.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just to add, I also commented out security and authorization: "enabled" on the mongod.conf file and restarted mongod on the Ubuntu server and I can now connect without a user+pass, so it's definitely not a connection issue.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I managed to fix it in the end. I was actually not creating the correct database, collection and user with the right roles to the new database. The Python code I was using was actually correct in the post.

What I needed to do on the Ubuntu server before enabling authentication was to create the db, then create the user, like so:

use playerdb
db.createUser(
{
user:"username",
pwd:"password",
roles: [ { role:"readWrite", db: "playerdb" } ]
}
)

Then when I enabled authentication and restarted mongod, connecting using the above Python code worked.

What a learning experience.